# How can I pass my dictonary into class with function?

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I want to declare a class using a dictionary and the ValueOrderedEnum library.

I have a dictionary

```
my_dict{'Blood':'4','Phlegm':'3','YellowBile':'2','BlackBile':'1'}
```

But I am totally clueless of how to set it as variables into this:

```
class Humor(ValueOrderedEnum):
   Blood = 4
   Phlegm = 3
   YellowBile = 2
   BlackBile = 1
```

Comment: You are presumably using https://pypi.org/project/ordered-enum/?

Comment: Yes, that is the one

Comment: I think you can simply write `Humor = ValueOrderedEnum('Humor', my_dict)`.

Comment: Inside the class?

Comment: @chepner It doesn't work anyway. I guess that's what I get for assuming they can be built like normal python classes without testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply call `ValueOrderedEnum` with your `dict` as an argument to create the desired enumerated type.

```
>>> from ordered_enum import ValueOrderedEnum
>>> my_dict = {'Blood':'4','Phlegm':'3','YellowBile':'2','BlackBile':'1'}
>>> Humor = ValueOrderedEnum('Humor', my_dict)
>>> Humor.Blood > Humor.Phlegm
True
>>> Humor.Blood, Humor.Phlegm
(<Humor.Blood: '4'>, <Humor.Phlegm: '3'>)
```

Calling `Enum` (or a subclass thereof) is a way to programmatically do what inheriting from `Enum` (or its subclass) does declaratively. (Which is to say, classes with `EnumMeta` as their metaclass behave quite differently from classes with `type` as their metaclass.)